# How to retrieve all sub-properties of a property even is its value is null in database (instead of Object)?

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

**(SOLUTION AT END OF POST)**

Consider a **query** called *userFetch* with the following definition:

```
type User_Details {
  phone_number: String
}

type User {
  name: String
  details: User_Details 
}
```

When fetching a **User** with the following data in database I don't get the sub-field *phone_number*.

```js
// in database
{
  name: "Joe"
}
```

Through GraphQL I get the following:

```js
// response
{
  name: "Joe",
  details: null
}
```

when I would expect:

```js
// expected response
{
  name: "Joe",
  details: {
    phone_number: null
  }
}
```

---

**How can I make GraphQL keep the subfields even if all nulls?**

This is an issue for my frontend when whole sub-objects are missing as in the previous example.

Thanks for your tips and tricks ;)

---

**EDIT: SOLUTION**

I understand that GraphQL is transparent and doesn't enforce any output format (simply pick what's available from the fetched data).
For my case I (sometime) want to enforce this behavior. Main case is when I'm using the response in the client interface and need to be able to play with all the sub-properties even if not yet set in the database.

Beforehand you've got to know that I've already build an environment around graphql which allows me lots of things (like getting the default/empty object of a type). *Not yet open sourced.*

To enforce a response with all the sub-properties whatever has been saved in the database I've created a **GraphQL Middleware** which **merges the resolved data with my default value/object**.

This way it's a simple add-on on my graphql endpoint which depending on a the request parameters allow me to force a full response or the minimalistic usual one :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GraphQL doesn't determine the value of a field, it is simply a transport layer. If your object looks like this:

```js
const user = { name: "Joe" };
```

And your query looks like this:

```
{
  user {
    name
    details
  }
}
```

The GraphQL engine can't figure out the actual details of your user, as the details are null (or undefined, which is the same for this matter). If you wish to send non-null `user.details`  you must fetch them from somewhere.
To be specific, if you want your response to look like this:

```
{
  name: "Joe",
  details: {
    phone_number: null
  }
}
```

The user you send must look like this:

```js
const user = {
  name: "Joe",
  details: {
    phone_number: null
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've worked around it as explained in my original post :)